# How do I use the setStartupBehavior API call?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to register event handlers when a document first opens up in Excel as it shows in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/run-code-on-document-open). However, it tells me that I need to configure my code to include this: Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load); I'm not too sure where I am supposed to use this. I created my project using the yeoman generator for Office.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you want the users to decide whether the add-in runs when the file opens or whether you want to ensure that it does. If you want the user to decide, include this line of code in an event handler for a button or other UI. There's a sample add-in that does this at: [Excel shared runtime scenarios](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/e8be8a77f555f4f5a55e3ed485a6b2078300b596/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-scenario#set-runtime-load-behavior).

If you want to ensure that the add-in runs whenever the file opens, then include the line of code in the `Office.initialize` method or `Office.onReady` method. The first time the file opens, the add-in will not run immediately and the user will have to manually invoke it. But, after that, the add-in will run whenever that file is opened.